# printing the number of substrings that start and end with 1 in a given string

Tags: arrays, c, string

For example, if the input string is “00100101”, then the output substrings should be “1001”, “100101” and “101”.

i think there is a mistake with function but not sure.
I got 2 errors[Line 24, col 6 [Error] conflicting types for 'binarysubstring' and Line 4, col 6 [Note] previous declaration of 'binarysubstring' was here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axfVf.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

long binarysubstring(int, char);

int main()
{
    int t,n,count;
    long r;
    char a[n+1];
    t=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%s",&a);
    r=binarysubstring(n, a[n]);
    printf("%ld",r);
}

long binarysubstring(int n,char a[n])
{
    int i;
    long r;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==1)
        {
            r+=1;
        }
    }
    r=((r*(r-1))/2);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Your compiler error tell you that you have two different definitions for your function `binarysubstring`. At the first place (line 3) the second parameter is a `char` whereas in the second definition that parameter is defined as `char a[n]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are multiple mistakes to process here, I'll try to explain and fix them starting from the errors you see on compilation.

First, your compilation error is because your function declaration takes a `char` as the second argument instead of a character *array*, line 4 should instead be

`long binarysubstring(int, char[]);`

You also should not be declaring the array size inside the function signature on line 18.

Your other immediate issue is that you initialize the buffer `char a[n+1];` on line 10 *before* the input to define `n` on line 12, and since you did not define a value when `n` was declared on line 8, line 10 will actually declare a character array of size n + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1, which cannot store any input.

With these three things fixed, the following code compiled for me with Clang-7:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

long binarysubstring(int, char[]); // Added the brackets here

int main()
{
    int t,n,count;
    long r;
    t=0;
    scanf("%d",&n); // Moved this...
    char a[n+1]; // ...to be before this
    scanf("%s", a);
    r=binarysubstring(n, a);
    printf("%ld",r);
}

long binarysubstring(int n, char a[/*Removed n, do not pass anything here*/]) 
{
    int i;
    long r;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==1)
        {
            r+=1;
        }
    }
    r=((r*(r-1))/2);
    return r;
}
```

However, this code always returns 0 because on line 24, your if statement compares each `char` to an *integer*, which is parsed to its ASCII code that is not the actual *character* of 1. As a result, `r` is never incremented because the condition is never true with the binary strings you are inputting, and it remains 0 up to your final sum formula, which then evaluates to 0 as well.

At this point, I'll give my attempt to implement what your question asks:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

long binarysubstring(unsigned short, char[]);

int main() {
    unsigned short n;
    printf("Input the length of your string: ");
    scanf("%hu", &n);
    char input[n + 1];
    printf("Input the binary string: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    long answer = binarysubstring(n, input);
    printf("Answer: %ld\n", answer);
}

long binarysubstring(unsigned short n, char a[]) {
    long r = 0;
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      if (a[i] == '1') {
        ++r;
      }
    }
    return r*(r-1)/2;
}
```

This assumes the input is a binary string. I use the same algorithm you appear to, counting the number of times 1 appears in the string with `r` and then returning the sum of the integers in the sequence from 1 to `r`, inclusive. It also happens to return 0 for binary strings of length 1.

Comment: As this is my first answer, I would appreciate anyone's edits or comments for incorrect information or formatting.

Comment: thanks a lot. your code worked and I understood all my errors except one. that why my string is being treated as _char_ but your code which also declared as _char_ took it as binary string?

Comment: If you're referring to the parameters, it is because my function signatures use `char[]` instead of just `char`. If you're referring to the comparison, in both your code and mine, `a[i]` is a `char`, but my code compares it to a "literal" char by wrapping the 1 in single quotes, preventing it from being treated as an ASCII code.